# Can the __cplusplus version be set purely from the compiler tools/environment?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, cmake, blender

I am linking against an external library in a C++ GCC project, on Ubuntu, compiled with cmake (The Blender Cycles renderer library):
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/Render/Cycles/Standalone

My local code requires C++11, so I set -std=c++11. But this causes a ton of nasty runtime crashes, as the library I am linking against doesn't have this set and has this code that makes it binary incompatible, if the __cplusplus versions difer (std::mutex and boost::mutex are different sizes):

```
#if (__cplusplus > 199711L) || (defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1800)
typedef std::mutex thread_mutex;
typedef std::unique_lock<std::mutex> thread_scoped_lock;
typedef std::condition_variable thread_condition_variable;
#else
/* use boost for mutexes */
typedef boost::mutex thread_mutex;
typedef boost::mutex::scoped_lock thread_scoped_lock;
typedef boost::condition_variable thread_condition_variable;
#endif
```

Everything is fine if I go into the Cycles library's Cmake file and add the C++11 flag manually, but that seems hacky. Is there anyway to force GCC to use a later compiler version from the command line, or GCC environment, when I rebuild the external library, without changing the external makefile?

Comment: You are still on Ubuntu?? The gcc version on Ubuntu are so old that they default to -std=c++03!! You should compile from source a newer version of GCC, they default to std=c++11 or std=c++14.

Comment: `Is there anyway to force GCC to use a later compiler version` - `-std` option sets C++ **standard** version, not a *compiler* version. And I guess there is no "latest standard version" for a compiler: it just supports **set** of the standards, and some of these standard is used by default. When configure external library with CMake, you may pass additional compiler flags to it: `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 ...`.